# How to restore a SQL Server bak file (Enabled FileStream ) to Docker version SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, filestream

I have SQL Server 2014 installed on Windows and enabled the FileStream feature. I backed up the database to a .bak file. Now I want to restore the file to my Docker container of SQL Server 2019. However, when I try to restore the .bak file, it fails. I searched for a solution and found out that the FileStream feature is not supported on the Docker version of SQL Server. Is there any way to restore the .bak file to my Docker version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is to remove the FileStream from the database before backing up.  You can add a non-filestream varbinary(max) column to store the blobs in the database instead of in the file system.

See, eg [How to Remove Filestream from a SQL Server Database](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5858/how-to-remove-filestream-from-a-sql-server-database/)